# Does Chromium use fontconfig mechanism?

Tags: linux, firefox, fonts, google-docs

I have a small but annoying bug with Google Docs in Firefox with font rendering. Bug details fully described on Bugzilla, briefly -- in Google Docs (and Sheets) Firefox substitute two fonts: sans-serif 'Arial' and monospace 'Courier New' with one **serif** font (that is Bitstream Vera Serif in my case) (see picture below).

But this bug is absent in Chromium.

Temporary workariound -- disabling loading of the [49-sansserif.conf](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/blob/master/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf) file (part of the fontconfig package) via removing symlink, fixes the bug.

So my questions is:

1. Does fontconfig mechanism is used by both browsers mentioned above?
2. Why Chromium recognized 'Arial' font as 'Arial' and 'Courier New' as 'Courier New', but Firefox not?

[image: Firefox font bug]

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, definitely**. Bug was disappear after reinstaling `ttf-bitstream-vera` package, so  mechanism of browsers interaction with the `fontconfig` is not affect to font rendering in this case.

Trivia: at this morning I decide to remove Bitstream Vera Serif font, with which Firefox substitute Arial and Courier New, I planned to see which font Firefox will use next, if Bitstream Vera Serif font will no exists in system. So I removed whole `ttf-bitstream-vera package`, and fonts in Google Docs began to render normally; moreover, after I installed ttf-bitstream-vera again, Google Docs works orrectly.